# Python Manage.py and Pycharm

Tags: python, django, server

python manage.py runserver not working in pycharm and giving this error even I have put manage.py in settings of Django in Language & Framework Django Tab.. what it could be?

```
    (venv) C:\Users\ionezation\PycharmProjects\ecomesite\ecs>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: Are you running the command in the ***Pycharm Terminal*** or ***normal ubuntu terminal/windows cmd*** ?

Comment: you need to configure virtualenv in pycharm

Comment: I typed pip install django and now it is working .. Pycharm needs Django installation from PIP .. weird really

Answer (score 1):

seems you need to specify python  interpreter
File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> icon gear wheel -> Add ->
Existing environment